# Utilize UnitOfWork with SqlDependency and Memory Cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

I've successfully incorporated my UnitOfWork pattern to have SqlDependency. So that means any query I send off to the database, if there are any changes made, a notification is sent.

```
public override IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
    int? numberOfEntities = null,
    IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null)
{

    IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query,
            (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    var actualNumberOfEntities = int.MaxValue;

    if (numberOfEntities.HasValue)
    {
        actualNumberOfEntities = Math.Max(1, numberOfEntities.Value);
    }

    notification = new ImmediateNotificationRegister<T>(Context, query);
    notification.OnChanged += NotificationOnChanged;
    return query.AsExpandable().Take(actualNumberOfEntities).ToList();
}
```

I would like to save the collection to a memory cache but I'm not sure how to do that at a generic level and have the collections remained filtered(if filtered). I can use the below methods if I would like to have everyitem, but I would like to know if I can save single entities or filtered collections

```
public void ClearCache()
{
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(MemoryCacheNameGetAll);
}

public void SetCache()
{
    if (MemoryCache.Default[MemoryCacheNameGetAll] == null)
        MemoryCache.Default[MemoryCacheNameGetAll] =
                Context.Set<T>().ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    SetCache();
    return MemoryCache.Default[MemoryCacheNameGetAll]
        as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

Comment: Please add more tags or more explanation about what you're talking about.

Comment: If you want to cache only one object, or a custom collection of objects, you need to give it a name, ex: `MyCustomCollection`, and then use `MemoryCache.Default["MyCustomCollection"]=collection`, to retrieve it you ask MemoryCache for that collection, after checking for null.

Comment: your notification is telling you only the number of objects in a table, but you can have updates too, like I told you few days ago, you do not need notification if you clear the cache after every crud op.